# Multiple Apache HTTP Clients in an Actor model implementation

Tags: java, concurrency, akka, apache-httpclient-4.x, actor-model

I have this architectural doubt here. There are multiple options and all seem to be valid, but I want to do the rightest thing.

I have this application heavily using the actor model with Akka. Some actors (not many) will perform outbound HTTP calls using Apache HTTP Client, typically against the same server all the time.

Now, I understand the creators of HTTPClient state that you generally would use one HTTP Client instance in your application and a pooled connection manager. While I totally understand why they're saying so, I feel like I should use one Http Client and one basic connection manager for each actor instance, because by doing so if something breaks in the client or connection manager, an exception is thrown, and the supervisor will restart the actor clearing whatever state may have persisted.

Am I going nuts? Any advice?

Comment: You can use the Akka's HTTP library. Ops, I didn't see the answer. There you go...already answered then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem once and ended up simply using [akka-http](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/index.html). ;-)

If you're stuck with the apache httpclient then I personally would do it per actor because of isolating state from each other as you've mentioned above.